# How can I convert integer value from query_hash_s in Azure Log Analytics to a VARBINARY(64) for sys.dm_exec_sql_text?

Tags: azure-sql-database, type-conversion

SQL Server errors are shown in Azure Log Analytics. Sometimes, the query_hash_s column is populated. But the values provided appear to be BIGINT. How can I use that value to find the actual text of the SQL statement using sys.dm_exec_sql_text? Simply converting the value to a VARBINARY(64) doesn't work.

Example value: 621553112374777528

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(64), 621553112374777528)
```

results in 0x12000001B81623384333A008, whereas sys.dm_exec_sql_text is looking for a value that looks more like this (this is a different value, shown only to illustrate the length difference):

> 0x02000000E5F7E122B77841FB561786311AFC20E00196B0D30000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: There's some absurdly complicated instructions [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_pfe_blog/2013/08/19/correlating-xe-query_hash-and-query_plan_hash-to-sys-dm_exec_query_stats-in-order-to-retrieve-execution-plans-for-high-resource-statements/). Does this help you at all?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik I gave it a try, and the "Single Query Hash comparison" produces a "Hash is not equal" result and the "Query Hash comparison extended to DMV" doesn't produce any result. I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: I still have no answer and am still using https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter manually, and then looking up the converted value (with 0x prepended) when searching in the plan cache or Query Store.

Answer (score 1):

This one was a head scratcher, but I got it working.
It seems like that the query_hash_s value must be declared as BIGINT prior to being converted to a BINARY value. Then you can look it up in dm_exec_query_stats by query_hash to get the sql_handle, and then look up in dm_exec_sql_text.

```
DECLARE @query_hash_s  BIGINT = 6999877919413064060

SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(8), @query_hash_s)

SELECT
        deqs.query_hash ,
        deqs.query_plan_hash ,
        dest.text
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
WHERE   deqs.query_hash = CONVERT(BINARY(8), @query_hash_s)
```

Comment: That worked for one value I tried, but not many others. It could be the queries are no longer in cache. The results of the conversion do match the results from https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter, so that's a big win. Thanks!